# Symfony: cannot fetch all the rows in a table via jsonresponse

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I am trying to fetch all the records in my "products" table via jsonresponse into my ajax script that could be further loaded in my twig template, but as of now the value returned is null by json,

following is my controller:

```
public function showAction($slug){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        if($slug == 'prod'){
            $repo = $em->getRepository('SystemBundle:Products');
            $q = $repo->createQueryBuilder('u');
            return new JsonResponse($q);
        }

}
```

following is my ajax function:

```
<script>
    function fetchprod() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/show/prod",
            dataType: "json"
        }).success(function(data){
            $('#contaiber').html(JSON.stringify(data.sum));
        });
    }
    fetchprod()
    setInterval(function () {fetchprod()}, 3000);
</script>
```

and this is my markup (just a container div to see what is returned):

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

I am not getting anything inside the div, but when I enter the url I can see "{}" displayed on the page (basically a blank array).

how can I solve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
if($slug == 'prod'){
    $repo = $em->getRepository('SystemBundle:Products');
    $q = $repo->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->getQuery();
    $products = $q->getResult();
    return new JsonResponse($products);
}
```

Comment: output: [{}], yet a blank array!

Comment: what are you getting in $product result ?? did you tried to take dump() . It might be possible that no data is returning from selected table.

Answer (score 0):

`$result = $q->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult(); to get one record 
$result = $q->getQuery()->getResult(); to get all record`

Probably is what you need to get the result first before passing it back via json.

Comment: I have used $result = $q->getResult();, and I got "[{}]" as output! still it is returning a blank array!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    if($slug == 'prod'){
        $repo = $em->getRepository('SystemBundle:Products');
        $q = $repo->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
        return new JsonResponse($q);
    }
```

simple, and works!